# Sass: Selecting the parent element with multiple nested selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass

Here's what I'm ultimately trying to do:

```
.books, .dvds, .magazines {
  article &.books {
    /* Wanting the selector to only be ".books article" */
  }
  article {
    /* Can apply to any of the `article` tags under .books, .dvds and .magazines */
  }
}
```

I've got some nested selectors and instead of breaking out a new `.books article` selector, I'd like to keep them nested, but still only target `article` elements under `.books`.

I did try this, and it works, but the output is `.books.books article`, which is redundant and makes me cringe:

```
.books, .dvds, .magazines {
    &.books article {
        /* Outputs ".books.books article, .dvds.books article, .magazines.books article"...boooo, hisssss */
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please say Why you use &.books

Comment: With SASS, using `&` selects the parent selector when it's nested.

Comment: I never understood nested syntax. Does that output `.books.books article` and not `.books.books article, .dvds.books article, .magazines.books article`?

Comment: @BoltClock Bah, you're right. So, even worse. :)

Comment: Eurgh. This is why I don't use it :P Anyway, I think you may have to use `@extend` somewhere rather than using `&`...

Comment: As far as I'm aware, what you're trying to achieve isn't possible. Furthermore, I'd suggest that just breaking this into two nested bits of code instead of trying to keep it all in one would be easier to read and maintain (and take up just as many lines of code).

Comment: Just wanted to note I get why reaching the parent from nesting >1 would be helpful. I like my BEM CSS to mirror my component markup hierarchy exactly. To my brain it just makes logical sense. I can scour the CSS much faster as I can simultaneously visualise the markup. This also helps visualise specificity etc. One day the world will catch up with my madness.

Answer (score 22):

What about something more like:

```
article {

  .books &,
  .dvds &,
  .magazines & {
    /* book, dvd, magazine shared stuff */
  }

  .books & {
    /* book stuff */
  }

}
```

compiles to:

```
.books article, .dvds article, .magazines article {
  /* book, dvd, magazine shared stuff */
}
.books article {
  /* book stuff */
}
```

Comment: This works because of the [amazing ampersand in sass](http://www.joeloliveira.com/2011/06/28/the-ampersand-a-killer-sass-feature/)!

Comment: It deserves to be featured so more people can see it