# Add ancestor selector in current SASS nesting

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass, modernizr

I would like to use Modernizr classes but I can't see how to do it properly with SASS in a current nesting selectors.

How to optimize:

```
.page-home
    .content
        .rows
            .row
                background: blue

        .images
            width: auto

html.no-touch
    .page-home
        .content
            .rows
                .row
                    &:hover
                        background: red

html.touch
    .page-home
        .content
            .images
                max-width: 50px
```

To render something like :

```
.page-home .content .rows .row {
    background: blue;
}
html.no-touch .page-home .content .rows .row:hover {
    background: blue;
}
.page-home .content .images {
    width: auto;
}
html.touch .page-home .content .images {
    max-width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.page-home
    .content
        .rows
            .row
                background: blue

                html.no-touch &:hover
                    background: red

        .images
            width: auto

            html.touch &
                max-width: 50px
```

Will render:

```
.page-home .content .rows .row {
  background: blue; }
  html.no-touch .page-home .content .rows .row:hover {
    background: red; }
.page-home .content .images {
  width: auto; }
  html.touch .page-home .content .images {
    max-width: 50px; }
```

See [SASS referencing parent selectors](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#referencing_parent_selectors_) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12714728/1134411) for another example.