# Apply li:hover only if html has class 'no-touch'

Tags: html, css, sass, modernizr

I am using Modernizr which sets up a `touch` or `no-touch` class on the `<html>` tag. Now I am using SASS and in a nested clause I had

```
li:hover {
  // ...
}
```

I would like to apply this definition only if we have `no-touch` on the `html` tag.

```
.no-touch li:hover {
  // ...
}
```

Doesn't work, since it's on the root. Is there a SASS shorthand or way to get what I want without creating a completely new CSS rule outside of all the definitions.

```
<html class="no-touch">
  <body>
    <div>
    <!-- a lot of HTML -->
               <ul>
                 <li> ... </li>
               </ul>
    <!-- /a lot of HTML -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I would use the `&` operator like this:

```
 &.no-touch {
   li:hover {

 }
```

It would append the `no-touch` rule only to the surrounding `ul` element, resulting the following generated CSS:

```
 ul.no-touch li:hover {

 }
```

Which doesn't cover the case, since `no-touch` is defined on `<html>` and not `<ul>`

Also taken from the SASS documentation:

> & will be replaced with the parent selector as it appears in the CSS

The parent selector does not reference to the `<html>` tag

Comment: @cimmanon But the `&` operator only adds it to the immediately surrounding element and not the outmost

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to explain how `&` didn't work for you. That description isn't totally clear.

Comment: @BoltClock Well, I added a HTML example which should make clear that the marked duplicate answer does answer a different scenario.

Comment: @Mahoni Still not seeing how this is not a duplicate of the other question.  You should try reading the entire answer.

Comment: @cimmanon Fair enough, added another example which explicitly shows why the `&` operator doesn't work for me

Comment: @Mahoni Did you even *look* at the answer?  There are 3 examples of code given.  One of them applies to your case.  I suggest you read it again.

Comment: ..in other words, `.no-touch & {  li:hover { .. } }` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Why would you reopen this?  It is a clear duplicate.

Comment: @cimmanon It's not an exact duplicate. The duplicate you linked to doesn't explicitly cover this. It merely states *" you can place the `&` at virtually any position you like [...]  this somehow breaks your nesting structure"*. I don't think it's a **clear** duplicate, as you're suggesting. I wasn't the only one who voted to open this.

Comment: @cimmanon That's a better duplicate in my opinion. Voted to close as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832042/add-ancestor-selector-in-current-sass-nesting .. btw, I don't think this question deserves the downvotes that it's receiving.